# HTML Form wont create new entries

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I am trying to create a basic form fill, where you can add a season or new entries and that will post to a databse and I can't seem to figure it out for the life of me. When I run it what I get is that the new seasons "Add more Episodes" buttons dont work and that the title for seasons are in the wrong place.

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    // create a variable
    $title=$_POST['Title'];
    $seasonNum=$_POST['SeasonNum'];


    //Execute the query
    $connect = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','123','mydatabase');
    $sql = "INSERT INTO $title(SeasonNum) $SeasonNum(myInputs[])";
    mysqli_query($connect, $sql);

    if(!$connect) {
        die 'Failed to connect because ' . mysqli_connect_errno();
    }
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<span id="responce"></span>
<h2>Season 1</h2>
<form method="post" action="">
<div id="dynamicInput">
      Entry 1<br><input type="text" name="myInputs[]">
</div>
 <br>
<input type="button" value="Add Another Episode"onClick="addInput('dynamicInput');">

<input type="button" value="Add Another Season" onClick="addSeason('dynamicSeason');">

<div id= "dynamicSeason">

</div>

<input type="submit" value="Add Show">
</form>
<script src="script.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript file (script.js)

```
var counter = 1;
 var limit = 3;
 var EpisodeAdd = 2;
 x=1;
 function addInput(divName){

       var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
       newdiv.innerHTML = "Entry " + (counter + 1) + "<br><input type='text' name='myInputs[]'>";
       document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
       counter++;

 }

 function addSeason(divName){
       i=1;
       x++;
       var h1 = document.createElement("h1");
     var h1Text = document.createTextNode("Season " + x);
     h1.appendChild(h1Text);
     document.body.appendChild(h1)
       while(i>0){
         var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
         newdiv.innerHTML = "h1Text Entry " + (counter + 1) + " <br><input type='text' name='myInputs[]'><br><input type='button' value='Add Another Episode' onClick='addInput('Dynamic'EpisodeAdd);'>";
         document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
         i--;
         EpisodeAdd++;
       }
       counter++;


 }
```

Comment: You've got a ton of problems in here...

Comment: I tried to fix a few of the errors (like the order of mysqli_query being after the connection is made) - and moved the js to separate file for better readability. Still, for the SQL I'm not even sure what it's trying to do. - Also added an if wrapper as Difster suggested.

Comment: What I was trying to do was make a new table, which was the name of the show and then the name of the columns would be 'Season 1', 'Season 2' etc. and then for then the user would enter the information for the name of the episode in the form, which would go under the columns.

Comment: You define `$seasonNum` and use  `$SeasonNum(myInputs[])` - see the spelling difference? -- I think what you should do is sanity checks... build a step, check that it works. Continue... That way the error messages you are probably receiving will be more useful.

Answer (score 0):

First problem: You're missing a comma here. Notice the change. Also, the `myInputs[]' thing doesn't make sense. Not sure what you're doing there.

```
mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO " . $title(SeasonNum) . 
        $SeasonNum(myInputs[]));
```

Also, you've got a lot of stuff out of order. You can't execute the insert query at the top of the script when it first loads. It should only do that when you submit the form. So wrap it in an `if` statement:

```
if($_POST['submit']){
$title=$_POST['Title'];
$seasonNum=$_POST['SeasonNum'];
mysqli_query($connect"INSERT INTO $title(SeasonNum)
            $SeasonNum(myInputs[]);

$connect=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','123','mydatabase');

if(mysqli_connect_errno($connect))
{
    echo 'Failed to connect';
}
}
```

There might be other problems too but until you get the basics sorted out, I don't know what they are. I'd suggest getting things in order and then posting a new question as you get closer to the solutions.